# How to download an image from url to use in Photoshop scripting (ExtendScript Toolkit)

Tags: javascript, photoshop, extendscript

In my Photoshop javascript (using ExtendScript toolkit), I need to download an image before processing it. I'm trying with wget, as such:

```
app.system("wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73950/IMG_1827%20%282%29.png > ~/Desktop/test.png");
```

Unfortunately, this produces an empty png file.

What's the correct way to download files from url when scripting with Photoshop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tried your wget command without luck. But it worked with curl for me.

```
app.system("curl -o ~/Desktop/test.png https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73950/IMG_1827%20%282%29.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working only for Mac, below is the way for both:

```
if ( Folder.fs.indexOf("Win") > -1 ) {//SYSTEM IS ONE OF THE WINDOWS
    app.system("cmd.exe /c \"bitsadmin /Transfer myDownloadJob " + imageUrl + " " + localImgPath + "\"");
}else{
    app.system("curl -o " + localImgPath + " " + imageUrl);
}
```