# How to download an image from url to use in ILLUSTRATOR scripting (ExtendScript Toolkit)

Tags: adobe

To place an image into Adobe Illustrator using the ExtendScript Toolkit is well documented:

```
var placedItem = doc.placedItems.add();
placedItem.file = new File("~/Desktop/xxx.jpg");
placedItem.position = [100,370];
```

Does anyone know how to place an image from URL into Adobe Illustrator. For example: https://www.bcgen.com/demo/IDAutomationStreamingDataMatrix.aspx?D=TEST123&PT=T&MODE=3&X=1&LM=1

In Photoshop one can use app.system(curl -o .....) as explanined here ([How to download an image from url to use in Photoshop scripting (ExtendScript Toolkit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001280/how-to-download-an-image-from-url-to-use-in-photoshop-scripting-extendscript-to/71211120#71211120)). But in Illustrator app.system() seems not to be available. Maybe do.script() is the right way to go but did not figure out how so far....

Answer (score 2):

JSXGetURL is meant to work with any Adobe Creative Cloud application that has ExtendScript support – InDesign, InDesign Server, InCopy, Illustrator, Photoshop…

JSXGetURL is implemented as an ExtendScript DLL/framework, written in C/C++.

This DLL allows you to access URLs (including https: or ftp:) straight from ExtendScript.

There is nothing to install – all you need to do is //@include a .jsx file which then loads the DLL.

See https://coppieters.nz/?p=577

Disclosure: I am the author of JSXGetURL.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33686249)

Comment: Sorry to be unclear, but I'd argue it does. Once you download JSXGetURL and add it to your script folder, you can simply do something like:

```//@include "JSXGetURL/JSXGetURLLoader.jsx"
var getURL = JSXGetURL();
var f = new File("~/Desktop/myImage.png");
var s = getURL.get("https://somewhere/myImage.png", f.fsName);``` 
Once the file is downloaded, it is a local file and can be placed as per usual.